# The pseudosphere in 2 and in n dimensions.

Tags: soft-question, smooth-manifolds, spheres

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudosphere), the pseudosphere is the surface of revolving a tractrix about its asymptote.

I have the following questions:

1. Does the half of the pseudosphere have a different name? I.e., the surface of revolving only the one "branch" of the tractrix about its asymptote.
2. The above surface (half of the pseudosphere?), as far as I understand, is a 2-dimensional surface, whose "base" is an 1-sphere. Does this generalise in higher dimensions? That is, does the n-pseudosphere have as its "base" an (n-1)-sphere?

Comment: Regarding question 2, the appropriate generalization turns out to be an (incomplete) embedding of hyperbolic $n$-space in $\mathbb{R}^{2n-1}$. You can find it in the introduction to the paper by Tenenblat and Terng, Bäcklund's Theorem for n-Dimensional Submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^{2n-1}$, Annals of Mathematics, 111 (1980), pp. 477-490.